# Get each height and center each div

Tags: jquery, slider

I use a jQuery slider (slider pro) and I want to center (horizontally and vertically) a div of text inside my differents slides. Each div of text have diffrent height. Unfortunately with the function that I wrote. It's take the height of the first div of text and apply it to the other div.

```
<div class="sp-slide">
    <div class="sp-text">
        This is the text that I want to center
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sp-slide">
    <div class="sp-text">
        I have different height
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sp-slide">
    <div class="sp-text">
        I have an another height
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery function :

```
function sliderText_center() {
    $('.sp-text').each(function() {
        var container = $('.sp-slide');
        var content = $('.sp-text');

        $(this).css("left", (container.width()-content.width())/2);
        $(this).css("top", (container.height()-content.height())/2);
    });
}
```

How to get each sp-text height independently ?

Comment: `$('.sp-text')` refer to all element has `.sp-text`. You should use `$(this)` instead. Also use `$(this).parent()` instead of `$('.sp-slide')`.

Comment: @Mohammad, Perfect ! that's run, thank you